# Marker Listener on Map in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am developing one application in that I am displaying locations  current location with database location in map using markers, Now  I am trying to add listener to current location marker,here listener applied to current location but other database markers also effected by listener,it raised exception while clicked on database markers in map,my requirement is listener applied to current location please verify where I made mistake in code

```
 public class ShowMapWhenLoginActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener, 
                                            OnMarkerClickListener{
GoogleMap _googleMap;
 LatLng myPosition;
 LocationManager locationManger;
private Marker mCustomerMarker;
private double latitude;
private double langitude;

private String TITILE = "start";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_map_when_login);

    _googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
            R.id.mapId)).getMap(); 

    LocationManager service = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    boolean enableGPS = service.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    boolean enableWiFi= service.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);


    /*if(!enableGPS || !enableWiFi){
        Toast.makeText(ShowMapWhenLoginActivity.this, "GPS signal not found", 
           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(intent);
    }*/

    locationManger = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String provider = service.getBestProvider(criteria, true);


    service.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, this);


    if(_googleMap==null){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Google Map Not Available",   
               Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    _googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);


}
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //locationManger.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0,   
              this);
    //_googleMap.clear();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arl = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) 
            getIntent().getSerializableExtra("arrayList");


    if(location!=null){
         latitude = location.getLatitude();
         langitude = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng latlang = new LatLng(latitude, langitude);

        myPosition = new LatLng(latitude, langitude);

    }
         if(arl.size()!=0){


            for(int j = 0;j<arl.size();j++){


          String lat =arl.get(j).get("lat").toString();
          String lng =arl.get(j).get("lng").toString();
          if ( !lat.trim().equals("") && !lng.trim().equals("") ) 
          {
          double Hlat = Double.parseDouble(lat.trim());
          double Hlong= Double.parseDouble(lng.trim());

          LatLng dabaseLocations =new LatLng(Hlat, Hlong);

          getOtherLocation(dabaseLocations);
          getCurrentLocation(myPosition);
          // Show current location with database locations

             }
           }
         }
     else{
             // Show  Current Location Only

            getCurrentLocation(myPosition);
    }

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
/*@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onRestart();
    Intent i = new Intent(ShowMapWhenLoginActivity.this,ShowMapWhenLoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
}*/

private void getOtherLocation(LatLng location){
     mCustomerMarker = _googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
     .position(location)
     .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE))
     .flat(true));


}
private void getCurrentLocation(LatLng location){
    _googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myPosition,5)); 
    _googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title(TITILE));

}
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if((marker.getTitle()).equals(TITILE)){

        Toast.makeText(ShowMapWhenLoginActivity.this, "clicked", 100).show();
    }
    return true;
}

}
```

LogCat

```
     03-10 16:17:47.482: E/AndroidRuntime(1395): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     03-10 16:17:47.482: E/AndroidRuntime(1395): java.lang.NullPointerException
     03-10 16:17:47.482: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):    at    
    com.technowellServices.traffic.ShowMapWhenLoginActivity.
    onMarkerClick(ShowMapWhenLoginActivity.java:172)
    03-10 16:17:47.482: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):     at    
    com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap$8.a(Unknown Source)
    03-10 16:17:47.482: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):     at c    
   om.google.android.gms.maps.internal.k$a.onTransact(Unknown Source)

     03-10 16:17:47.482: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):    at    
    android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:310)
    03-10 16:17:47.482: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):     at ejn.a(SourceFile:84)
    03-10 16:17:47.482: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):     at maps.e.bl.a(Unknown Source)
    03-10 16:17:47.482: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):     at maps.ay.c.a(Unknown Source)
    03-10 16:17:47.482: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):     at maps.ay.n.c(Unknown Source)
    03-10 16:17:47.482: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):     at maps.ay.m.a(Unknown Source)
   03-10 16:17:47.482: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):  at maps.ay.bg.b(Unknown Source)
   03-10 16:17:47.482: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):  at maps.ay.bc.onSingleTapConfirmed(Unknown Source)
    03-10 16:17:47.482: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):     at maps.bo.g.onSingleTapConfirmed(Unknown     
   Source)
    03-10 16:17:47.482: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):     at maps.bo.i.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
   03-10 16:17:47.482: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):  at        
   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:130)

    03-10 16:17:47.482: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):     at android.os.Looper.loop(SourceFile:351)
    03-10 16:17:47.482: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):     at   
    android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3814)

    03-10 16:17:47.482: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):     at     
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

    03-10 16:17:47.482: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):     at 
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:538)
    03-10 16:17:47.482: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):     at    
     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
     03-10 16:17:47.482: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):    at    
     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:659)
    03-10 16:17:47.482: E/AndroidRuntime(1395):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native     
     Method)
```

Comment: try this: `if(marker.getTitle().equals(TITILE)`

Comment: no  same result exception

Comment: Try out `if(marker.equals(mCustomerMarker)){`

Comment: not applied any listener if i write like this

Answer (score 0):

Try out as below :

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if((marker.equals(mCustomerMarker)){

        Toast.makeText(ShowMapWhenLoginActivity.this, "clicked", 100).show();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: It will be reflected only when your `getOtherLocation` method will gets called and your markers will be added on map.

Comment: i want to apply listener to current location marker